# pth root of a prime is not in $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to show that $\sqrt[p]{\ell}\notin L:=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{5}]$ where $\ell$ and $p$ are primes and $\zeta_p$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity $(\zeta_p)^p=1$.

I edited my post since what I wrote wasn't satisfying. The route I followed was sterile and the trick is to stay over $K_p:=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p]$ since we can then apply the "Kummer" trick, no need for more sophisticated tools.
Suppose for a contradiction that $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{5}]=\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_p,\sqrt[p]{\ell}]$. We write $\alpha=\sqrt[p]{5}$, $\beta=\sqrt[p]{\ell}$ and $K=K_p[\alpha]=K_p[\sqrt[p]{\ell}]$ to emphasis the point. Then one can write:

$\beta=c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+\cdots+c_{p-1}\alpha^{p-1}$ whit $c_i\in K_p$ (1)

Take a generic automorphism $g$ from $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K_p)$ defined by $g(\alpha)=\zeta\alpha$. What I call the Kummer trick is to see that $g(\beta)/\beta$ is a $p$-th root of unity ($\big(g(\beta))^p=g(\beta^p)=g(\ell)=\ell=\beta^p$ since $\ell$ is invariant.

So $g(\beta)=\zeta^k\beta$ for some $k$  (2)

Then you compose $(1)$ by $g$ and use (2):

$g(\beta)=c_0+c_1\zeta g(\alpha)\cdots+g(\alpha^{p-1})=c_0+c_1\zeta^r\alpha\cdots+\zeta^r\alpha^{p-1}$ and you find that $\beta=c_{i_0}\alpha^{i_0}$, which raised to the $p$-th power gives $\ell=q5^r$, a contradiction.

I took this from K. Conrad's [Linear independence of characters](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf).

Comment: Are you familiar with how ramification works in number fields? This is exactly the sort of problem ramification theory is meant to handle; it's enough to show that $\ell$ doesn't ramify in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p, \sqrt[p]{5})$, and there are plenty of ways to determine whether a prime ramifies (e.g., checking if it divides the discriminant of the number field).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I don't know this. All I could achieve so far was to say that if $\sqrt[p]{\ell}\in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{p}]$, then since there exists $\gamma$ primitive in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{p}]$, we would have  $\sqrt[p]{\ell}=q\gamma$ with $q$ rational. Then $\ell=q^p\gamma^p$ would not be prime if I can show that $\gamma^p$ is rational.

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt[5]{p}$ or $\sqrt[p]{5}$? Anyway, the general idea is to study how primes factor in number fields: if $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can compute the factorization of $p$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$. The *ramified* primes (i.e., primes whose factorization in $\mathcal{O}_K$ isn't squarefree) are exactly those dividing the *discriminant* of $K$. But if $K$ contains a root of $p$, then clearly $p$ is ramified. Milne's notes on algebraic number theory are a good place to learn about this.

Answer (score 1):

@user26857   Let $K = \mathbf Q(\zeta_p)$ and $L = K(\sqrt [p] {5})$ . The question amounts to show that $ L\neq K(\sqrt [p] {l})$ except in an obvious particular case. In your « Kummer trick »,  the mix of the additive and multiplicative structures complicates things. Besides, in your final equation $l = q. 5^r$, if $q$ is merely in your field $K_p$ , I can’t see a contradiction . Can you elaborate ?

The ghist of Kummer theory is to use the multiplicative structure alone. Because  $K$ contains $\zeta_p$, Kummer says that $ L = K(\sqrt [p] {l})$ iff the two subgroups of $K^*$/ ($K^*)^p$ generated by $5$ and $l$ coincide, iff there exists $1\le i\le p-1$ such that $5.l^i = x^p$ , $x\in K^*$. Since $5$ and $l$ are in the ring of integers $A := \mathbf Z[\zeta_p]$ , $x$ must be also in $A$. Norm down to $\mathbf Z$ to get $5^{p-1}.l^{i(p-1)} = y^p$. Excluding the particular case where $l = 5$ , this equation is impossible because of the exponents and of the factoriality of $\mathbf Z$ .